# Show a spinner while the listview loads with data

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm gathering a lot of files, and showing them in a listview. Most of the workload is within the constructor of the adapter. Is there a way I could use Asynctask and show a spinner till all the data is gathered. Does that mean I'd have to instantiate the adapter's constructor within the doInBackground method? How do I go about doing this?

Also, this list is contained within a tab. I'm using a viewpager. So due to the work being done in the constructor, the scrolling to this particular tab is a major stutter.

Comment: Hi, the problem is, I'm loading this list in a viewpager, so scrolling to this page leads to a major stutter, specially if there are a lot of files to gather. That is my main concern here. The answer linked as duplicate doesn't help.

Comment: I understand now (wasn't clear before), I will remove the comment. Sadly I cannot undo the flag (boo SO), but I'm sure that'll get marked 'disputed' now, with your update.

Comment: Is there a reason this is being done in the constructor for the adapter. Maybe this is work that should be done in an `AsyncTask` and then the results passed into your adapter. That way while your `AsyncTask` is running you could show the loading image instead of your `ListView`

Comment: This is from an app I made quite a while back. It was my first app, and the software design is a nightmare. I'm afraid I'll break something if I try to move things around, so I'm trying to find an alternative.

Comment: To avoid your stutter problem you will have to stop loading the data on the UI thread. The easiest solution to this it to load it in an `AsyncTask` doing it that way also makes it easy to show a loading icon when you start your task and replace the loading icon with the listview once the task has finished. Imo this is the way to go

Comment: That's how I do it right now. But this was my first app, and it was just tinkering more than anything. It's gone quite big. I also made a huge blunder by using SharedPreferences instead of databases. So moving things around is really going to upset everything. Maybe sometime in the future I'll remake the app, but can't do it right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can instanciate the adapter using an empty list before starting your AsyncTask. In your onPostExecute of the AsyncTask, you can update the list with your data and then call the `notifyDataSetChange` method of the adapter.
You could as well add a ProgressBar and hide it in the onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right you are looking for a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html). Here is an example:

```
class yourClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog.setMessage("Wait for list to fill up...");
            showDialog();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            //Fill in your code to populate the list
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
             hideDialog();
        }
}

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Dont forget to declare your pDialog like this :`private ProgressDialog pDialog;`